# Differentiate between different strings and fill strings in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two strings that I need to differentiate between. They both have text before and after, and I can't seem to figure out how to make it find each string and parse out its relevant information.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim toPrimary As String
Dim toCC As String  

For Each cell In Range("A2:A350")
    If cell.Value Like "*.USA.*" Then 'This is the first one
        toCC = toCC & ";" & "USA@email.com"
    ElseIf cell.Value Like "*.Burrito.*" Then
        toCC = toCC & ";" & "Durr@ito.com"
    ElseIf cell.Value Like "*.USA.Taco.*" Then 'This is the second
        toCC = toCC & ";" & "taco@bell.com"
    End If
Next
```

I am expecting that *.USA.* and *.USA.Taco.* will fill the toCC field with different information. If it makes any difference, *.USA.* only has three characters afterward (i.e., *.USA.Pie.*), whereas *.USA.Taco.* has that same string 'Taco' after 'USA.'

Comment: How comfortable are you with using regular expressions for this?

Comment: One problem is that `*.USA.Taco.*` also matches `*.USA.*`, so you need to put the taco first. But IMO life would be simpler with regex.

Comment: Question: why are you iterating 348 rows if at the end of the day you're only ever adding 3 addresses? Does any of these instructions mean to concatenate `cell.Value` into `toCC` at any point?

Comment: Hi @Mat'sMug. Yes, it does need to concatenate. Essentially it checks one column to see if any of the above strings exist. If they do, it then adds the relevant email to the string toCC. Ideally, it would match each once so that there wouldn't be duplicates, too. 

I have never used regex before.

Comment: Ok, looks like you took away too much of the code then. Please [edit] your question so that `cell.Value` is getting concatenated into `toCC`. Is the range located in a `ListObject` / table? Because if so the code can be made tremendously more expressive and robust.

Comment: I've given you an answer that would fix the matching problem, ignoring the missing concatenation issue.

Comment: @Mat'sMug, my mistake. It does not concatenate. Rather, each new email address is added in as it loops through the relevant columns. I've updated the code above to better highlight this. All of the information being pulled/referenced exists in an exported spreadsheet, so I do not have anything changing or updating in the sheet.

Comment: So... just to be clear: you're ultimately building a list of 348 emails, 3 of which are unique. IOW worst-case all rows match condition 1 and `USA@email.com` gets 348 copies of the same email? That can't be right...

Comment: In essence, yes. And it did not dawn on me until I started adding more email addresses to the test sheet.

Comment: I've edited my answer to leverage a keyed `Collection` to ensure uniqueness, and illustrate how to use `Join` to *join* array elements with a delimiter. Note that doing that removes the superfluous `;` you have at the beginning of your final `toCC` string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
If cell.Value Like "*.USA.*" Then 'This is the first one
    '...
'...
    '...
ElseIf cell.Value Like "*.USA.Taco.*" Then 'This is the second
    '...
End If
```

if `cell.Value` matches `*.USA.Taco.*`, then it *also* matches `*.USA.*`, and given how you've ordered the conditions, if anything matches `*.USA.*` then it doesn't matter what else it matches, because everything else is in an `ElseIf` block.

Flip them around: verify that `cell.Value` matches `*.USA.Taco.*` *before* you check if it matches `*.USA.*`:

```
If cell.Value Like "*.USA.Taco.*" Then
    '...
ElseIf cell.Value Like "*.USA.*" Then
    '...
ElseIf cell.Value Like "*.Burrito.*" Then
    '...
End If
```

---

You'll want to only list each recipient **once** - nobody wants to receive 300 times the same email (assuming their mail server doesn't just block the sender).

Instead of building a string like this, make a keyed collection:

```
Dim ccRecipients As Collection
Set ccRecipients = New Collection

If cell.Value Like ...
    ccRecipients.Add "USA@email.com", Key:="USA@email.com"
ElseIf cell.Value Like ...
    ccRecipients.Add "Durr@ito.com", Key:="Durr@ito.com"
...
```

This will throw an error when a duplicate address is added to the collection. So make a dedicated procedure to do it safely:

```
Private Sub AddUniqueItemToCollection(ByVal value As String, ByVal items As Collection)
    On Error Resume Next
    items.Add value, key:=value
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And then invoke it:

```
Dim ccRecipients As Collection
Set ccRecipients = New Collection

If cell.Value Like ...
    AddUniqueItemToCollection "USA@email.com", ccRecipients
ElseIf cell.Value Like ...
    AddUniqueItemToCollection "Durr@ito.com", ccRecipients
...
```

Then you can iterate the unique items in the collection, to add them to an array:

```
ReDim ccAddresses(0 To ccRecipients.Count - 1)

Dim ccAddress As Variant, ccItem As Long
For Each ccAddress In ccRecipients
    ccAddresses(ccItem) = CStr(ccAddress)
    ccItem = ccItem + 1
Next
```

And now you can use `Join` to build the final list of recipients and separate each one with a semicolon:

```
Dim sendToCC As String
sendToCC = Join(ccAddresses, ";")
```

That way you won't be spamming anyone's inbox!

Comment: Morning @Mat'sMug! I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried setting AddUniqueItemToCollection as its own Private procedure, as well as adding it to the my current procedure, both to no avail.